# Webpack sass additional data config causes styles duplication

Tags: vue.js, webpack, sass

I use additional data property in vue.config.js to add variables, mixins etc globally, but i noticed that looks like those styles are duplicated per route(i use dynamic page import),
how to prevent duplication?

ps i use vue3 vuecli vuerouter sass